# How to avoid instantiation of variable after button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am running a Sql query whose where clause changes everytime when button click occurs.

Now the where clause consists of an index to the list. When the button click happens ,page load occurs which causes the index value intialisation.

```
int i=0;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    string str = lst1.ElementAt<string>(i++);
    qr = "Select BdId,First_Name,Last_Name,Age,Gender,Relationship_status,Birthday from [User] where BdId='" + str + "'";
    da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(qr, con);
    da2.Fill(ds2);
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "  " + i.ToString();
}
```

How can I avoid this happening? I want index value to be global so that it doesn't instantiate again every time button click occurs.

Thanks

Comment: Aside from anything else, you should parameterize your SQL to avoid SQL injection attacks...

Comment: A non local variable called `i`. Shudder.

Comment: Your problem is a bit underspecified. In particular you didn't describe how it should behave if the website is opened in multiple tabs.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes i ll take care of that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time there is a request for your page, a **new** instance of that page-class is created to handle that request. So any fields are re-initialized.

You can store a value in ViewState to remember a value over various requests:

```
private int TheIndex
{
   set { ViewState["TheIndex"] = value; }
   get 
   {
      if (ViewState["TheIndex"] == null)
         return 0;
      return (int)ViewState["TheIndex"];
   }
}
```

And use `TheIndex` instead of `i`.

**EDIT**
Plus, as CodeInChaos notes, use a more descriptive name. That will help in understanding the code if someone else (or you yourself in a few months) needs to maintain this code.

Comment: `TheIndex` is a pretty bad name too. I'd use something like `CurrentElementIndex`. And preferably I'd even use a more descriptive word than `Element`.

Comment: Thanks so much it works yes i ll take care of all the mistakes i have made

Answer (score 0):

You can store the variable in `Session` object provided by ASP.Net. You can check [this](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/) tutorial also.

```
if(Session["CurrentIndex"] != null) i = (int) Session["CurrentIndex"];
else Session["CurrentIndex"] = i;
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Looks broken to me. Just open two tabs at the same time, and you get strange interference between them. I'd rather include the counter in a hidden input field, and post it back.

Comment: A hidden input will lead to separate counters, a session to a shared counter. A shared counter can lead to very strange effects and needs to be coded *very* carefully.

Comment: +1 Hmmm now it depends upon OP's requirement. How counter needs to be handled.